# Getting ImportError When running EXE created by pyInstaller

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

I'm using numpy in a python code, it runs successfully when running it as python. But when converting it to executable using pyInstaller, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "numpy\core\overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numpy\__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "numpy\__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "numpy\core\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "c:\test_numpy.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.26.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test_numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "numpy\__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
[58772] Failed to execute script test_numpy
```

When doing it from a different PC, the EXE runs successfully.